# setuid/setgid wrapper for python script

Tags: python, permissions, wrapper, elevated-privileges, setuid

I have a Python script that I wish to be able to be run as the system user `guybrush` with UID 200 and group `guybrush` with GID 200.

At the moment my Python script (located in `/path/to/script.py`) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os

print "uid: %s" % os.getuid()
print "euid: %s" % os.getgid()
print "gid: %s" % os.geteuid()
print "egid: %s" % os.getegid()
```

My attempted C wrapper (`scriptwrap.c`) looks like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setuid(geteuid());
    setgid(getegid());
    return execv("/path/to/script.py", argv);
}
```

I then compile, chown, and chmod the wrapper as follows:

```
$ gcc scriptwrap.c -o scriptwrap
$ chown guybrush:guybrush scriptwrap
$ chmod 6755 scriptwrap
```

Yet when I run scriptwrap, I get the following output:

```
uid: 1000
euid: 1000
gid: 200
egid: 200
```

So for some reason only the GID is being set (my normal UID is 1000). What can I do to fix this?

**Edit:** If I chown the script to `root:root` and run it, the UID, eUID, GID, and eGID are all set to 0.

Also, this is on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I figured this out (and learnt a bit in the process). Embarrassingly my initial problem was caused by a typo in my Python script: I was printing out the GID under the label `euid`, and the eUID under the label `gid`. Oops.

So the eUID and eGID are actually set correctly -  great. But the UID and GID still aren't set despite my use of `setuid` and `setgid` in the C wrapper.

It turns out that this is due to the behaviour of `setuid` and `setgid` differing based on whether you are `root` or not: If you are root and you call `setuid`, it sets your real UID and your effective UID to whatever you pass it in, if you are not `root` it just sets the effective UID ([source](https://www.osso.nl/blog/setuid-seteuid-uid-euid/)). So my use of `setuid` (and `setgid`) are essentially no-ops.

However it is possible to set the real UID and GID by using the `setreuid` and `setregid` calls:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setreuid(geteuid(), geteuid());
    setregid(getegid(), getegid());
    return execv("/path/to/script.py", argv);
}
```

Which results in the following output from the (corrected) Python script when run:

```
uid: 200
euid: 200
gid: 200
egid: 200
```